# Setting server timezone in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

How do you permanently (not session level) set the timezone in YugabyteDB YSQL?
Is this a G-flag or via `ysql_pg_conf`?
Can you give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `--ysql_timezone` gflag in yb-tserver: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#ysql-timezone